# Workflows are getting suspended for other users than me

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I created a site in SharePoint 2013 and some workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013. Now I am testing it and I can see that everything is working great when I am operating only on items, that I created.

- When I try to start a workflow on item created by another user an error occurs and whole workflow is suspended.
- When I try to run site workflow, which loops through all items in my list it will work well until it meets item created by another user.

I am the site owner, I have full control permissions. I gave other users access to my site by adding `NT Authority\Authenticated` Users to default Site Members group.

Do you know what is causing suspending my workflows?

**Edit:**

Error description:

> RequestorId: 67c7e8af-caf5-10a9-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["57"],"SPRequestGuid":["67c7e8af-caf5-10a9-a476-6227e56256d6"],"request-id":["67c7e8af-caf5-10a9-a476-6227e56256d6"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0,
>   private"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Negotiate","NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4617"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Fri, 07 Jul 2017 04:32:40 GMT"]} at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: what's the suspend error code?  please click on **!** to get suspend error message

Comment: are you using system account ?

Comment: M.Qassas - I didn't noticed it and I terminated all my suspended workflows. For now everything is OK (see my comment below). Gautam Sheth - no, I am using my own account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, You should be aware of

- The user should have a `contribute` permission to the SharePoint list that associated to the workflow with its related `Task List` and `History list`.
- The **Default Member Group** doesn't have a `Contribute` permission by default.

So I think your workflow has been suspended because of the **permission issue** so try to edit your Member Group permission and assign the `Contribute` permission.

---

Also, make sure that you have **elevated Workflow permissions** by doing the following:

- Allow workflow to use app permissions.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow.
- Develop the workflow to wrap actions inside an App Step using SharePoint Designer.

I mentioned the detail steps at [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: I granted a full control permission to a workflow as your described in linked article and now everything is OK. I need to do more tests, especially on another accounts, which will take some time and after that I will be able to clearly say if your solution solves whole my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it's worked, Please don't forget to **Mark** and **Upvote** the correct answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue! in case you have additional query related to your question you can come back here and comment on this answer, in case you have additional questions you should ask anew questions!

Comment: Error was caused by checking option **Create items and edit items that were created by the user** in List's Advanced settings and I needed to uncheck it. I know that by doing it everyone with Contribute permissions will be able to edit all items stored in list but it won't be a big problem for me in this case. However, your solution @M.Qassas gives me informations that I also used in my site for similar purposes described in main post so I thank you again for your help.